# A 2Gbps backbone bandwidth of a switch with 10/100Mbps ports

Tags: switch

What does a "2Gbps backbone bandwidth" of a 10/100 Mbps switch mean?
The switch has 8(downlink)+2(uplink) ports.

Comment: What brand/model switch is that? Sounds like a home-grade model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely you mean "back*plane* bandwidth". The backplane is the component connecting all the ports, and all data needs to move across it.

A 2 Gbit/s backplane is sufficient to run ten 100 Mbit/s ports on - 100 Mbit/s port speed equates to 200 Mbit/s full-duplex data rate each. That way, the switch is fast enough to be *non blocking* - data throughput is only limited by port speed.